# How control buttons on listview in android

Tags: android

I m in little problem
I add the buttons on listview but i can't add the listener on that buttons.i used the custom listview in which we give xml view to custom adapter and set that adapter on listview and this listview placed in another xml file.

if anyone add the buttons on listview and handle that buttons with listeners then please help me because my project is stop for this reason

Comment: You should post your code showing how you try to do it. This way it is much easier to point out what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using custom adapter, in that getview you can add listener for you button.
Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181994/help-regarding-onclick-event-on-an-item-of-listview-custom-row-layout/4182148#4182148)