# android Custom ListView selected row on button click

Tags: android

I have custom listview with textview and button. I set the button click handle in the xml files and the implementation in the ListActivity.

The problem is when i click the button, I cant get which selected row that i click.

Regards

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181994/help-regarding-onclick-event-on-an-item-of-listview-custom-row-layout

Answer (score 7):

Are you using your own adapter?  If so, you could certainly set a tag on the button, indicating it's position in the list.

something like

```
@Override
getView(... position ...){
//do stuff
  buttonView.setTag(new Integer(position));
//do stuff
}
```

Then later you can get check the `view.getTag()` `onClick()`