# Event handle on customized ListView

Tags: android, listview

```
public class ActivityForShow extends Activity

{
     //have a ListView layout
     ListView.setAdapter(SingleRowAdapter);
}

public class SingleRowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    //every row has a CheckBox ,a TextView and a Button
}
```

Now I want to handle CheckBox and Button events,do some background work and show result in a dialog.
But how to getRefences of Checkbox and Button in ActivityForShow?
findViewById() will cause Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to do that in the ActivityForShow class. Instead, register all event handlers inside of your SingleRowAdapter#getItem(int) method (you will have have to override this). In that method you create the view for the given row, so you know what the row is (position) and you can register event handlers for the CheckBox, Button, etc

Comment: But in SingleRowAdapter class I cannot create a Dialog,right?

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious it gives error with finviewbyid method because it is used for when reference by xml ele. You can use this link for study:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: I know how to findViewById in SingleRowAdapter class,I want to know how to get references in AcitvityForShow class.

Comment: What is "ele" - does that mean "element"?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to handle the `onCheckedChanged` event or `onClick` event in `ActivityForShow`.

If so, have `ActivityForShow` create a `OnCheckedChangeListener` instance and `OnClickListener` instance (e.g. as local anonymous inner classes) and have `ActivityForShow` give them to `SingleRowAdapter` (e.g. as constructor params) to attach to the checkbox and button widgets as their callbacks.

Alternatively, define your own custom handler interface(s) to be called when the button is clicked or the checkbox is checked. Have `ActivityForShow` to instantiate an instance of the custom interface(s) with code to process the event.  Have `ActivityForShow` give them to `SingleRowAdapter`.   Finally, have `SingleRowAdapter` create event handlers to attach to the checkboxes and buttons - these event handlers simply call your own custom handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following link may help you, [event on an item of ListView custom row layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181994/help-regarding-onclick-event-on-an-item-of-listview-custom-row-layout/4182148#4182148).