# How to display list of check box with icon and name (android)

Tags: android

I want to display list of check boxes with one `ImageView` and `TextView` in it.

```
+-----------+----------+----------+
| CHECK_BOX | ImageVew | TextView |
+-----------+----------+----------+
```

This list should be multiple selectable.
How to prepare This list?
How to get all selected check boxes and corresponding TextView value?

Can some one please provide sample code for this.

Thanks,
PP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an adapter and bind it to a listview. The layout seems simple enough (LinearLayout with horizontal orientation). You will need to extend the BaseAdapter class.

Assume your class that holds the data looks something like this:

```
public class BasicClass {

// Holds the ID for the row
public int ID;

// Holds the resource ID for the imageview
public int ImageID;

// Holds the text for the textview
public String Text;
```

}

Your getView method will look something like this:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    final BasicClass e = (BasicClass) getItem(position);

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.checkbox_list_item, null);
    }


    TextView txtTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_list_item_txtTitle);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_list_item_img);
    final CheckBox chSelected = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_list_item_cbSelected);

    txtTitle.setText(e.Text);
    img.setBackgroundDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(e.ImageID))

    chSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                //Logic comes here to add and remove the selected items to a ArrayList<BasicCLass>

        }
    });


    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use Listview Custom adapters by extending BaseAdapter class.
Refer this [links](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/)
For multiple selectable refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181994/help-regarding-onclick-event-on-an-item-of-listview-custom-row-layout/4182148#4182148)