# ListView with different actions according to View

Tags: android

I want to make a listview with two image views in it and two different actions for the listener case the image the user touches.So this is my code

```
l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        switch(arg1.getId()) {
        case R.id.addView :
        //do this
            break;
        case R.id.imageView1 :              
        //do this
            break;
        }
```

Comment: u want click on image or list..? n u hv two image in all row?

Comment: Tags may also be used to differentiate items having shared handler. for example in XML you set tag as ADD or IMG and here you can get tag by calling getTag and then compare or use switch if you set numeric values

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181994/help-regarding-onclick-event-on-an-item-of-listview-custom-row-layout).

Comment: @CapDroid: please write in a readable language. Not everybody might understand `n u hv`...

Answer (score 1):

You need to make those images clickable with setClickable and set an OnClickListener on each.

When something inside a ListView item is interactive then it will steal the click event to its parent.