# Getting Content from Imageview in CustomListViewAdapter to share via Facebook

Tags: android, listview, imageview, share

I was creating an Chat like CustomListview with a textview and and Imageview for Each Post like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If someone sends a picture it is shown in the ImageView. Now i would like to implement the function to click the Imageview and get the content to share it for example on facebook. So the Basic Question is how do i get the Content of the Imageview by Clicking on it. Just passing the source does not work, since it changes if someone sends another Picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the bitmap from the ImageView using this code:-

```
Bitmap bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx this helped also but mostly this helped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181994/help-regarding-onclick-event-on-an-item-of-listview-custom-row-layout

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the contents of the ImageView into a Bitmap then on to a File before you share it. If you already have the contents in a file, use the file url instead of doing it again. The android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND will show all the options on the phone which are will to receive that type of message (in this case image/*).

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();

        // Save this bitmap to a file.
        File cacheDir = this.getExternalCacheDir();
        File downloadingMediaFile = new File(cacheDir, "abc.png");
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Now send it out to share
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/*");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + downloadingMediaFile));
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Send Image."));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.